# Why can't I insert certain characters into a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, special-characters, collation

I am trying to do a MySQL insert and I am getting an error message like this:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xA0' for column 'foo' at row 1
```

This happens with both `\xA0` and `\x96`.

I am using PHP and I am passing this query to `mysqli_query()`:

`INSERT INTO ttest1 (foo) VALUES("test\xA0")`

Here's the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE ttest1 (
    test_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    foo VARCHAR(32))
```

Here is the character set and collation info for MySQL:

```
character_set_client        utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database      utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8mb4
character_set_server        utf8
character_set_system        utf8

collation_connection        utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database          utf8_general_ci
collation_server            utf8_general_ci
```

The collation for the `foo` column is uft8_general_ci.

So why am I getting that error with this setup and what is the best fix?

Answer (score 1):

There are no valid utf8 encodings between `\x80` and `\xFF`, so the error is correct.

Code point 160 (0xA0) (also known as `&#160;` or `&nbsp;`), in utf8, is a 2-byte character, encoded as `0xC2` `0xA0`.

Similarly, code point 150 (0x96) is encoded as `0xC2` `0x96`.

Encode your string with valid utf8 is the correct solution.

I'm a MySQL DBA, not a PHP expert (my bronze PHP tag badge notwithstanding) but apparently PHP 7 introduced [unicode codepoint escape literals](https://secure.php.net/manual/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) so you can apparently use `"\u{a0}"`.

Comment: Switching the text to utf8 is preferred.  But if you cannot, then switch the connection to `latin1` instead.